# Why am I getting this error when trying to push to github after committing?

Tags: javascript, git, parceljs

I'm working on a Javascript project using parcel as a bundler, whenever I try to push to the repo I get the following error in the terminal.

```
Counting objects: 40, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (40/40), done.
Writing objects: 100% (40/40), 1.45 MiB | 198.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 40 (delta 26), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (26/26), completed with 12 local objects.
remote: error: Trace: 13191e15dbdeb1dcd7186474dd8ff7cf93ebf2c7d42752d4fd9a2e73f37fa5eb
remote: error: See http://git.io/iEPt8g for more information.
remote: error: File .parcel-cache/data.mdb is 116.10 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
remote: error: File .parcel-cache/data.mdb is 106.80 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
remote: error: GH001: Large files detected. You may want to try Git Large File Storage - https://git-lfs.github.com.
To https://github.com/nezmustafa123/recipe_app.git
 ! [remote rejected] main -> main (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/nezmustafa123/recipe_app.git'
```

There was a caching folder that was created by parcel that I deleted but it still comes out with the same error.
Does anyone have any idea as to what I can do?
Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+remove+large+file+history

Comment: You should definitely not commit `.parcel-cache` to your git history - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60695778/what-is-the-cache-folder-in-parcel-bundler-is-it-necessary-to-push-the-cache/60723960#60723960)

Answer (score 0):

.parcel-cache/data.mb is larger then 100 mb's.
check if you need to push this file to your github otherwise put it in a .gitignore file

Comment: Thanks how do I add it to gitignore? 
Should I used the cached option in the terminal?